# Mapping (x,y) to single number value

Tags: java, algorithm

I want a function to map the (x,y) value to a single number value and corresponding reverse mapping in Java.

For example (2,34) should map to some value 100 and if we have 100 we should be able to find (2,34).

Comment: That doesn't add up. The function takes in 2 variables or 1?

Comment: What's the range of possible values for `x` and `y` ?

Answer (score 9):

Well, if you have a maximum value for one of them, then yes. Say `y` is limited to 0...9999, then could can do:

```
int num = x * 10000 + y;
```

(assuming of course that the result will fit in the type - you can possibly upgrade to a wider type like `long` if necessary). Then, to go back:

```
int x = num / 10000;
int y = num % 10000;
```

Comment: this will fail if the calculation result is bigger than an integer can hold. "num" also needs to stay in the integer range.

Comment: @fatih, I took it as a given that they would have to "fit", I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: @paxdiableo Agreed. Just trying to point out one possible non mentioned flaw. Now you have mentioned that as well :)

Answer (score 5):

If you've got an upper limit (say `100` is the higher for `x` in `(x,y)`), then you could associate any `n` to a pair of values `(x,y)` with this function: `n = x * 100 + y`.

If you don't have any limit things get more difficult. A way to associate a number belonging to `R`, to a number of `R^2` is that of enumerating diagonals. Look at this example, it's a matrix where the `(x,y)` cell contains the `n` associated to it:

```
1  2  4  7  11 ..
3  5  8  12 ..
6  9  13 ..
10 ..
..
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember, primitive numbers are just a bunch of raw bits. If your numbers are 32-bit integers (`int`), you could conveniently pack two of them into one 64-bit integer (`long`). Something like this:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
long c = ((long) a) << 16 | b;

...

a = (int) (c >> 16);
b = (int) (c & 0xffff);
```

Comment: This is coming quite a bit late, but why did you left shift by 16 only? Shouldn't it be 32 to accommodate 32 bit integer `b` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).
Something like `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` seems to work well for your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class hash {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
    HashMap<List<Integer>,List<Integer>> g=new HashMap<List<Integer>,List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> xys=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> ss=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Enter the coordinates in (x,y)");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("x");
    int n1=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    System.out.println("y");

    int n2=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    xys.add(n1);
    xys.add(n2);
    int d=(int)(Math.pow(xys.get(0),xys.get(1)));

    ss.add(d);

   g.put(xys,ss);
   g.put(ss,xys);
        List<Integer> r= g.get(ss);

        List<Integer> r1=g.get(xys);

        System.out.print("Hash for the value (x,y) mapping");
        System.out.print(r1);


        System.out.print("Hash for the value N, reverse mapping");
        System.out.println(r);


}
}
```

Comment: i have created a function f(x,y) as x^y, whats my problem is my range of x is 0 to 1000 and y is 0 to 1000, it will not fit in int i.e ( if (234,567) will be 234^567) . i want a function hash function f(x,y) that will return integer not long number.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep them as a String.

```
String a = "(2,34)";
String b = "100";

Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put(a, b);
m.put(b, a);

/*print*/
System.out.println(m.get(a));
System.out.println(m.get(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the background for this requirement?

If the range of x, y values is unlimited, then there is no way to do this in a unique way (so that you can always reverse the process).

If the range of the numbers is limited, then you could do the following: Suppose that x and y are `int` values both in the range 0 to 99. Then you calculate the result by: `z = 100 * x + y`. The reverse would be: `x = z / 100` and `y = z % 100`.

Comment: Even if the range of x and y is unlimited it is possible. Consider Cantor's enumeration of the rationals.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's essentially the same answer as the top rated answer by paxdiablo (and we answered at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative strategy based on paxdiablo's answer is to use the decimal point, so you would put the x component before the decimal place and the y component after it.

This can entail some messy string handling, but doesn't have the limitation that you need to be able to bound one of your coordinates.

Comment: Mwahhh - Why did I get downvoted? Please give me feedback as I'm a noob and learning my way. I thought my contribution was valid!

Comment: Just offering my thoughts: floating points are not ideal for this since they can be truncated, specifically the fractional part. So once you start extracting, some rounding errors may crop in and what used to be (999999, 999999) ends up being (999999, 999998) after extraction.